# What is faster? Framebuffer color attachment or full screen texture quad?

Tags: opengl, opengl-es, textures, framebuffer

I want to draw fullscreen frames of a sequence, and switch between them fast. I saw that I could attach multiply color attachments to a framebuffer.

I'm wondering if it could be far cheaper to use renderbuffer attachments instead of the current textured quads method.

How can I switch between attachments by the way? Is there a maximum number of attachments?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to draw fullscreen frames of a sequence, and switch between them fast.

Drawing images always means uploading the data to a texture and drawing a quad using that texture. Look into Pixel Buffer Objects to implement asynchronous data upload and glTexStorage (OpenGL-4.2 feature) for how to bolt the memory layout down.

> I saw that I could attach multiply color attachments to a framebuffer.

The framebuffers this applies to are off-screen framebuffer objects, and not the on screen framebuffer. I.e. this won't help you in any way.